# Phalcon ispatcher has detected a cyclic routing

Tags: php, phalcon, dispatcher

I create a new project with Phalcon framework.

For begin, my environment is :

- Phalcon 3.2.12
- Windows 10
- Xampp / PHP 7.2

At this time, I have created one login page in the index. When I launch my application, I have this message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: Dispatcher has
>   detected a cyclic routing causing stability problems in
>   \public\index.php:32

Line 32 :

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

There is my dispatcher in `services.php` :

```
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function () use ($di) {
    $evManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

    $evManager->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function ($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
        switch ($exception->getCode()) {
            case PhDispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
            case PhDispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
                $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'show404'
                ));

                return false;
        }
    });

    $dispatcher = new PhDispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($evManager);
    return $dispatcher;
});
```

There is my `IndexController` :

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setLayout('login');
    }

    public function show404Action()
    {
        $this->view->setLayout('login');
        $this->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found");
        $this->view->pick('index/404');
    }
}
```

There is my `ControllerBase` :

```
public function beforeExecuteRoute($dispatcher)
{
    $isValid = true;

    // check auth
    if ($dispatcher->getControllerName() !== 'index') {
        $isValid = false;

        $this->view->disable();

        $this->response->setStatusCode(401, 'Vous devez vous identifier pour     accéder à votre environnement.');

        if (!$this->request->isAjax()) {
            $this->response->redirect('index');
        }
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

<kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath('..'));

/**
 * Define APPLICATION_ENV (DEV,STAGING,PREPROD,PROD)
 *
 * @var APPLICATION_ENV string
 */
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV',     (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']) ?     $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] : 'PROD'));

/**
 * Read the configuration
 */
$config = include APP_PATH . "/app/config/" . strtolower(APPLICATION_ENV) .     ".config.php";

/**
 * Read auto-loader
 */
include APP_PATH . "/app/config/loader.php";

/**
 * Read services
 */
include APP_PATH . "/app/config/services.php";

/**
 * Handle the request
 */
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

If I put a `var_dump` at the begin of method `beforeExecuteRoute`, I don't see the result of `var_dump`.

Have you an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

probably you forward to something that can't be found. Try to rename **show404** to **showNotFound**, you can inspect the $dispatcher->getControllerName() and getActionName() during the afterExecuteRoute event to see why your handler or action can never be found

```
public function showNotFoundAction()
{
    $this->view->setLayout('login');
    $this->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found");
    $this->view->pick('index/404');
}
```

And

```
            $dispatcher->forward(array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'showNotFound'
            ));
```